# Retrieving an item from a datatable with a schema

Tags: c#, datatable, schema

I have a datatable with an associated schema. In general, I know how to retrieve an item from a row.

My question is, does the presence of a schema impact the retrieval in any way?

For example, without a schema I might use something like:

`double otherNumber = dt.Rows[i].Field<double>("DoubleColumn");`

since I know otherNumber is double.

But since the schema tells the datatable that DoubleColumn contains doubles, could this be simplified to something like

```
double otherNumber = dt.Rows[i]["DoubleColumn"];
```

with the casting implied because of the schema?

Comment: schema is just another set of tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  `dt.Rows[i]["DoubleColumn"]` will always be typed as `object` as far as the compiler is concerned, regardless of what it is at runtime.  You will need to force cast it either the way you already done have, or this syntax is fine too:

`double otherNumber = (double)dt.Rows[i]["DoubleColumn"]`